# Java - Read a txt file from a PHP webpage URL

Tags: java, php, url, io

First of all, I'm a newbie to Java and my English is bad, so hope you can understand my problem.

I want to read the text file from this URL: http://www.cophieu68.com/export/metastock.php?id=AAA

Okay, let me explain. This is a Vietnamese stock data website and the link above point to the file **aaa.txt** which contains the information of the stock with codename is AAA. And I can take the other stocks info by just modifying the value of the **id** variable.

And my problem is what I get is a bunch of HTML code, not the text file I expect (**aaa.txt**)

And here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.cophieu68.com/export/metastock.php?id=AAA");
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        System.out.println(urlConn.getContentType());  //it returns text/html

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

        String text;

        while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(text);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site seems to be [sniffing the user-agent](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_sniffing) to decide what content to send down.

If you [spoof the user-agent](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing) as shown below, it works as you'd expect - the response is the plain-text file:

`urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/20121223 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8");`

As you can probably tell, this pretends that the user-agent is Firefox 3.8 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the link (http://www.cophieu68.com/export/metastock.php?id=AAA) is send as an attachment. If you have access to the PHP file you should just do nothing but print the data and include

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

in your PHP file

Comment: That isn't the problem. If you visit the URL in your browser, the site sends back the .txt file but if you hit the URL as in the code, an HTML version of that data is served up. See my answer and suggested change; it seems to fix the problem.